# @Html.RenderAction and CSS

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How do I apply a class to the following so that I can apply a specific css style to it?

The rest of the  consist of anchor tags  so I can easily apply a class but where do I stick it on this @Html.RenderAction?????

```
<li>@{Html.RenderAction("CartSummary", "ShoppingCart");}</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RenderAction will output a PartialView so I guess your class attribute should be put in the view (the one you call from the method CartSummary in ShoppingCartController) or inside the  `<li>` that call it (maybe with a DIV)

Comment: I did consider applying the class to the <li> tag but I am looking to create a block menu vertical style from the <ul> but do not think I can apply the features I want to the <li> tag I need to go one step lower and would normally apply to the <a> tag but the render action is not an <a> tag?

Comment: RenderAction renders what you told to. Surely you have a partialview connected to the ActionMethod that you invoke.

Comment: I do yes a CartSummary partial view  @Html.ActionLink("Cart (" + ViewData["CartCount"] + ")",
"Index",
"ShoppingCart",
new { id = "cart-status" })

Comment: Inside it you can add your class: @Html.ActionLink("Cart (" + ViewData["CartCount"] + ")", "Index", "ShoppingCart", new { id = "cart-status", @class="myClass" }) (beware of the @ before `class` because is a keyword)

Comment: Ok so this @class = "nav" will be picked up in the css file and apply the style?4

Comment: It will output a tag `<a>` with `class="nav"`. Then I don't know how you will style it, but should work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

RenderAction does not support passing in an object containing html attributes, like most other MVC helper methods do, so you cannot apply a css class directly using this method. Either you can wrap the output of RenderAction in a div with your css class from the parent view, or you can add a wrapper div to the output of the action itself.

Answer (score 0):

Why u don't want to use `<a href="@Url.Action("index", "shoppingcart")" class="@yourClass" id="yourId">Cart (@ViewBag.CartCount)</a>`

Be simple.